# Omnibus Test for 3 or more Dichotomous Variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data

I would like to ask whether there is an omnibus test to determine whether the proportions across three or more dichotomous variables are different. If so, then what is the name of the test.

For example, suppose that participants are asked to state whether they like red (yes/no), blue (yes/no) and orange (yes/no). The results indicate that 60% of participants stated that they like red, 65% of participants indicated that they like blue, and 57% of participants indicated that they like orange.

Is there a test to determine whether these proportions (i.e., 60%, 65% and 57%) are different at the population level?

Comment: Cochran's Q test is a nonparametric, for dichotomous data, repeated-measures "ANOVA". Use it.

Comment: This can also be a simple multilevel regression problem if you have the original data, not just summary statistics.